# AWS Cognito dataset and Google Identity Toolkit error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, google-identity-toolkit

I am using the new(somewhat)   [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/) and I am facing a strange issue.

The JWT token generated by it is the following:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "qwYevA"
}
{
  "iss": "https://identitytoolkit.google.com/",
  "aud": "950882198692-jrb8d5t979qahaechf5gd4t3g59gpvou.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "iat": 1444275809,
  "exp": 1445485409,
  "user_id": "05244125885327377646",
  "email": "**********@gmail.com",
  "provider_id": "facebook.com",
  "verified": false,
  "display_name": "NOT_MY_NAME",
  "photo_url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/c155.48.597.597/s50x50/notmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphoto.jpg?oh=notmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphoto&oe=notmyphoto&__gda__=notmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphotonotmyphoto"
} 
{
*signature*
}
```

I am properly setting the *iss*:

```
CognitoSyncClientManager.addLogins("https://identitytoolkit.google.com/",
                  idToken.getTokenString());
```

The error appears whenever I try to sync a dataset:

```
 Dataset dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myTestDataset");
    dataset.put("myTestKey", "myTestValue");
    dataset.synchronize(new DefaultSyncCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Dataset dataset, List newRecords) {
            System.out.println(dataset.get("myTestKey"));
        }
    });
```

The error log:

```
com.google.identitytoolkit.demo E/DefaultSyncCallback: Failure occurred during sync
***: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.exceptions.DataStorageException: Failed to list records in dataset: myTestDataset
***:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.internal.storage.CognitoSyncStorage.handleException(CognitoSyncStorage.java:293)
***:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.internal.storage.CognitoSyncStorage.listUpdates(CognitoSyncStorage.java:152)
***:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.DefaultDataset.synchronizeInternal(DefaultDataset.java:388)
***:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.DefaultDataset$1.run(DefaultDataset.java:149)
***:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
***:  Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '{https://identitytoolkit.google.com/=eyJhb---*MASSIVE-JWT*---c5demjsRlQtqjz8A}' at 
'logins' failed to satisfy constraint: Map keys must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 128, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1, 
Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w._/-]+] (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: ab0d6028-6d80-11e5-ac9f-33bc83bfc548)
......
***: failed to synchronize myTestDataset
```

---

So, what could I be doing wrong?

This is my first time working the AWS and I am fairly new with JWT aswell. Any help is appreciated.

I should mention that I am using classes and samples from this project: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

Answer (score 2):

Google's OpenID Connect issuer name is "accounts.google.com", and that's what should be passed as the first parameter of addLogins instead of ""https://identitytoolkit.google.com/" for Google tokens.

However, it looks like your token actually specifies "https://identitytoolkit.google.com/" as issuer. If that's the kind of tokens you are receiving from the Identity Toolkit, I'm afraid you won't be able to use them to authenticate with Google using Cognito as that is not a valid OpenID Connect issuer [according to this](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig). It might be worth asking the Identity Toolkit guys about that, because it looks like a bug on their side.

Comment: Thank you. I saw your answer on the AWS forums. The guys at Google should see this question, since they are now using StackOverflow under the tag google-identity-toolkit as a forum.